# locale-gen generates not selected locales

Tags: 18.04, server, locale

I found, that on my home server, running Ubuntu Server 18.04, I've selected quite a few locales, I actually don't need. I only want `en_US.UTF-8` and `de_DE.UTF-8`, since the whole system is configured to use only these.

So, first, I tried the "Debian way" by running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and then deselected all besides the two I actually wanted. After that the system automatically regenerates the locales, but, unfortunately, more than I selected:

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
de_DE.UTF-8... done
en_AG.UTF-8... done
en_AU.UTF-8... done
en_BW.UTF-8... done
en_CA.UTF-8... done
en_DK.UTF-8... done
en_GB.UTF-8... done
en_HK.UTF-8... done
en_IE.UTF-8... done
en_IL.UTF-8... done
en_IN.UTF-8... done
en_NG.UTF-8... done
en_NZ.UTF-8... done
en_PH.UTF-8... done
en_SG.UTF-8... done
en_US.UTF-8... done
en_ZA.UTF-8... done
en_ZM.UTF-8... done
en_ZW.UTF-8... done
```

Then I tried directly editing `/etc/locale.gen`, but it's all fine in there, since only the two I actually want are not commented out, so it should work. I've checked the file multiple times from top to bottom.

Still, running `locale-gen` manually, yields the same result as above.

So I wonder if this is a bug or a feature? Is the file maybe cached somewhere or is there another configuration file I'm not aware of? I've already tried restarting the system, but as expected, this didn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The many English locales are probably there because you installed the English language packs. You should see them by running:

```
cat /var/lib/locales/supported.d/en
```

So a way to make the list shorter is to remove the English language packs:

```
sudo apt purge language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
```

Comment: You are correct! Although this system never had a GUI installed there were some language-packs installed, maybe as a dependency now not used anymore... Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue in my case. I have a server, these packages are not installed, these locales are not selected, but all of them (and others) are generated each time...

Comment: @logoff: Then your problem is different. Please ask a new question.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have the same OS, and the same problem exposed in the question. more locales than selected are generated. and this answer doesn't solve it.

Comment: @logoff: And if you want help to sort it out, ask a new question with details describing _your_ case.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @GunnarHjalmarsson! I added another response with the solution that works for me.

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that works in my case, that I find more complete than [the accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1301926/87242).

If I edit my locales editing file `/etc/locale.gen` or selecting them with command `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, when I select any locale of a language I got locales for all the variants of this language. Example, if I select only `en_US.UTF-8`, I got this list:

```
en_AG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
en_AG.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_AU.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_BW.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_CA.utf8                                     
en_DK.utf8                                      
en_GB.utf8                                      
en_HK.utf8                                      
en_IE.utf8                                      
en_IL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
en_IL.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_IN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
en_IN.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_NG                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
en_NG.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_NZ.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_PH.utf8                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
en_SG.utf8                                     
en_US.utf8           
en_ZA.utf8           
en_ZM                
en_ZM.utf8           
en_ZW.utf8
```

Which obviously is not what I want.

**My solution:**
After selecting my preferred locales with previous commands, I edit the specific language file in `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/`. In my example, I edit file `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en`, which contains the complete list of locales I showed previously. I leave only this line:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

Then I execute the command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales -f noninteractive` and I got only my preferred locales, not all the variants I don't want. This works with multiple languages, and I feel so useful with the ones with many variants (Spanish, English, etc.).

I hope this helps others in this situation like me.

Tested in Ubuntu server 18.04 and 20.04.

Comment: `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en` is provided by the `language-pack-en-base` package, so it seems to be installed even if you said otherwise in a comment on the other answer. Editing a package owned file is generally not a good idea, since the changes will be overwritten at next update of that package.

Comment: I confirmed again that this package is NOT installed at all with command `dpkg -s language-pack-en-base`. and the file exist. anyway, how I select which locales I want to install, not having all the variants? I found only this way